# Are "malloc(sizeof(struct a *))" and "malloc(sizeof(struct a))" the same?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This question is a continuation of [Malloc call crashing, but works elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761594/malloc-call-crashing-but-works-elsewhere)

I tried the following program and I found it working (i.e. not crashing - and this was mentioned in the above mentioned link too). I May be lucky to have it working but I'm looking for a reasonable explanation from the SO experts on why this is working?!

Here are some basic understanding on allocation of `memory` using `malloc()` w.r.t `structures` and `pointers`

- `malloc(sizeof(struct a) * n)` allocates `n` number of type `struct a` elements. And, this memory location can be stored and accessed using a `pointer-to-type-"struct a"`. Basically a `struct a *`.
- `malloc(sizeof(struct a *) * n)` allocates `n` number of type `struct a *` elements. Each element can then point to elements of type `struct a`. Basically `malloc(sizeof(struct a *) * n)` allocates an `array(n-elements)-of-pointers-to-type-"struct a"`. And, the allocated memory location can be stored and accessed using a `pointer-to-(pointer-to-"struct a")`. Basically a `struct a **`.

So when we create an `array(n-elements)-of-pointers-to-type-"struct a"`, is it

1. valid to assign that to `struct a *` instead of `struct a **` ?
2. valid to access/de-reference the allocated `array(n-elements)-of-pointers-to-type-"struct a"` using `pointer-to-"struct a"` ?

```
data * array = NULL;

if ((array = (data *)malloc(sizeof(data *) * n)) == NULL) {
    printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
    return -1; 
}
```

The code snippet is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    typedef struct { 
        int value1;
        int value2;
    }data;

    int n = 1000;
    int i;
    int val=0;

    data * array = NULL;

    if ((array = (data *)malloc(sizeof(data *) * n)) == NULL) {
        printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
        return -1; 
    }   
    printf("allocation successful\n");

    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
        array[i].value1 = val++;
        array[i].value2 = val++;
    }   

    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
        printf("%3d %3d %3d\n", i, array[i].value1, array[i].value2);
    } 

    free(array);
    printf("freeing successful\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT: 
OK say if I do the following by ***mistake***

```
data * array = NULL;
if ((array = (data *)malloc(sizeof(data *) * n)) == NULL) {
```

Is there a way to capture (during compile-time using any `GCC` flags) these kind of unintended programming typo's which could work at times and might blow out anytime! I compiled this using `-Wall` and found no warnings!

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match the actual questions in the rest of your text above...

Comment: Also, why would you want to assign the result of `malloc` to the wrong thing and then dereference it?  I don't understand the premise of the questions.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I do it by mistake and not intentionally! so Isn't the program suppose to crash when I do that?!

Comment: Regarding the edit: don't write `array = malloc(sizeof(data) * n)`. Instead, write `array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * n);`. It doesn't help the compiler any, but it helps you allocate the right type because you don't have to name the type, you just have to remember to put a `*` before the name of the pointer you're assigning to. I don't think there's anything in GCC to enforce this, but if you look around you might find a lint-style tool that would enforce style rules around the use of `malloc`.

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj your code is not correct it's working because the val variable is to small if it was bigger it will fail

Comment: @oussama I know this code is wrong and its insane to do those pointer assignment. But I was looking for an explanation on why it could work without crashing. Your answer seems to be reasonable.. That is the explanation I'm looking for! +1 for your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding.

> malloc(sizeof(struct a) * n) allocates n number of type struct a elements.

No, that's just what one usually does use it as after such a call. `malloc(size)` allocates a memory region of `size` bytes. What you do with that region is entirely up to you. The only thing that matters is that you don't overstep the limits of the allocated memory. Assuming 4 byte `float` and `int` and 8 byte `double`, after a successful `malloc(100*sizeof(float));`, you can use the first 120 of the 400 bytes as an array of 15 `double`s, the next 120 as an array of 30 `float`s, then place an array of 20 `char`s right behind that and fill up the remaining 140 bytes with 35 `int`s if you wish. That's perfectly harmless defined behaviour.

`malloc` returns a `void*`, which can be implicitly cast to a pointer of any type, so

```
some_type **array = malloc(100 * sizeof(data *)); // intentionally unrelated types
```

is perfectly fine, it might just not be the amount of memory you wanted. In this case it very likely is, because pointers tend to have the same size regardless of what they're pointing to.

More likely to give you the wrong amount of memory is

```
data *array = malloc(n * sizeof(data*));
```

as you had it. If you use the allocated piece of memory as an array of `n` elements of type `data`, there are three possibilities

1. `sizeof(data) < sizeof(data*)`. Then your only problem is that you're wasting some space.
2. `sizeof(data) == sizeof(data*)`. Everything's fine, no space wasted, as if you had no typo at all.
3. `sizeof(data) > sizeof(data*)`. Then you'll access memory you shouldn't have accessed when touching later array elements, which is undefined behaviour. Depending on various things, that could consistently work as if your code was correct, immediately crash with a segfault or anything in between (technically it could behave in a manner that cannot meaningfully be placed between those two, but that would be unusual).

If you intentionally do that, knowing point 1. or 2. applies, it's **bad** practice, but not an error. If you do it unintentionally, it is an error regardless of which point applies, harmless but hard to find while 1. or 2. applies, harmful but normally easier to detect in case of 3.

In your examples. `data` was 4 resp. 8 bytes (probably), which on a 64-bit system puts them into 1. resp. 2. with high probability, on a 32-bit system into 2 resp. 3.

The recommended way to avoid such errors is to

```
type *pointer = malloc(num_elems * sizeof(*pointer));
```

Answer (score 8):

No.

`sizeof(struct a*)` is the size of a *pointer*.
`sizeof(struct a)` is the size of the entire struct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But could you please elaborate on why the above code snippet is working! ..Isn't that suppose to crash?

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj: Undefined Behavior does not mean the program will always crash,it just means the program is ill formed and you cannot define the behavior of it.

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj: **Undefined behavior** is what's supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

This `array = (data *)malloc(sizeof(data *) * n)` allocates a `sizeof(data*)` (**pointer**) to struct `data`, if you want to do that, you need a your `array` to be a `data** array`.

In your case you want your pointer to point to `sizeof(data)`, a structure in memory, not to another pointer.  That would require a `data**` (pointer to pointer).

Answer (score 1):

> is it valid to assign that to struct a * instead of struct a ** ?

Well, technically speaking, it is valid to assign like that, but it is wrong (UB) to dereference such pointer. You don't want to do this.

> valid to access/de-reference the allocated array(n-elements)-of-pointers-to-type-"struct a" using pointer-to-"struct a" ?

No, undefined behavior.

Comment: It is certainly safe to cast (or directly assign) the result of a call to `malloc()` to the "wrong" pointer type.  `malloc()` has no concept of types, it just allocates sequences of bytes.  Undefined behavior only results from writing past the end of the sequence of bytes that you asked `malloc()` to give you.