# malloc nulling other variables

Tags: c, malloc

I am using the following function

```
int parse_headers(char *str, struct net_header *header)
{
    char *pch;
    struct net_header *h, *temp;

    pch = strtok(str, "\n");
    header->name = pch;

    h = malloc(sizeof(struct net_header));
    header->next = h;
    while ((pch = strtok(NULL, "\n")) != NULL)
    {
        h->name = pch;

        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct net_header));
        h->next = temp;
        h = temp;
    }
    return N_SUCCESS;
}
```

Up until the line `header->next = h`, everything works as planned. However, after the line `h = malloc(sizeof(struct net_header));`, the variables `pch` and `str` for some reason turn to `NULL` (I set breakpoints to find this). After the line `temp = malloc(sizeof(struct net_header));`, `header` also turns to `NULL`. Clearly, I have some kind of memory management issue, but I can't seem to find what it is. The `header` argument is initialized like this immediately before I call the function

```
header = malloc(sizeof(struct net_header));
```

`struct net_header` is declared as

```
struct net_header
{
    char *name;
    char *content;
    struct net_header *next;
};
```

I ran Xcode's static analyzer, which found no issues. I also have no compiler warnings or errors. I am running this program on Mac OS X 10.9.

Why are my variables being nullified after I call `malloc()`?

Comment: Does *str turn to NULL or str itself? str is a copy of a pointer on the stack or in a register and should never be affected by a call to malloc even in case of some memory management issue. The same applies to pch.

Comment: `header->next = h;` will be a problem if `header` is NULL. How sure are you that `header` is not NULL?

Comment: @Meixner prior to `malloc`, it contains a string (`"foo"`), but after the call it is `NULL`, so I would say `str` itself.

Comment: @RSahu When I set the breakpoint anywhere before the while-loop, `header` points to a valid object, and its `name` value is properly set.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. How do you call `parse_headers()` and how parameters are defined? Is this the only thread of execution?

Comment: @AntoJurković I call `parse_headers()` from another function (not `main()`), and I only have one thread. `str` contains an HTTP response and `header` is an empty struct (I show how I declare it in the question).

Comment: Is it possible that HTTP response is just changed before you finish parsing? I used your code and fixed string for `str` and it was parsed without problem.

Comment: There is nowhere else I can think of that `str` would be modified, so I doubt it.

Comment: try assigning to h with any other function call than `malloc()`. If you get similar behaviour (variables change arbitrarily), you suffer from stack corruption.

Comment: @Chris Probably a dumb question: Did you debug optimized code? If yes, all reported values may be wrong since the debugger may be looking at the wrong places.

However, your code has one issue: malloc() is not guaranteed to initializes the returned memory to 0x00, i.e. your pointers inside the struct may contain some garbage unless overwritten.

Comment: @Meixner the code's not optimized, so I believe the values are correct.

Comment: @mfro I'm thinking this is that's the issue, and I'm trying to find where I went wrong to cause the corruption.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to keep strtok result you have to dup it, with for example `strdup`

```
int parse_headers(char *str, struct net_header *header)
{
    char *pch;
    struct net_header *h, *temp;

    pch = strtok(str, "\n");
    header->name = strdup(pch);

    h = malloc(sizeof(struct net_header));
    header->next = h;
    while ((pch = strtok(NULL, "\n")) != NULL)
    {
        h->name = strdup(pch);

        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct net_header));
        h->next = temp;
        h = temp;
    }
    return N_SUCCESS;
}
```

you need to call `free` somewhere to free the memory

Comment: For more info, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100214/strtok-segfault

Comment: This is helpful, but I still have the nulling problem.

Comment: That's only if `str` might be changed and you want `header->name` to be independent of `str`. So far, this has nothing to do with his problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error, running on Mac OS X 10.10, and there is no problem with your code, it works perfectly.

Your problem comes from another call to `malloc()` with a bad size like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29372619) and in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761615/4773612), generally caused by passing a pointer's size instead of the real size of variable's type.

I cannot tell you where since I don't see your entire code running before this "bad call", and I couldn't ask in comments because I don't have enough rights.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll look into this when I get home and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Any news about your issue ? Do you succeed to fix it ?